# Difference between LambdaExpression.Compile and Delegate.CreateDelegate

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

In the process of optimizing reflection calls, I'm experimenting with using [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=net-6.0) and [`LambdaExpression.Compile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.compile?view=net-6.0) to turn my `MethodInfo`s into faster delegates.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127042/what-does-lambda-expression-compile-method-do), I expected `LambdaExpression.Compile` to perform significantly better because it would generate actual MSIL for the method call -- somewhere close to a direct method invocation.

However, after benchmarking, I noticed that both techniques have roughly the same performance.

My hypothesis is that the overhead I'm getting when calling a delegate created using `LambdaExpression.Compile` is due to the use of delegates itself. To confirm, I created another benchmark in which I manually created delegate directly invoking the method, and it had similar performance.

Therefore, my question is: is there any difference in the delegate object generated by `LambdaExpression.Compile` and `Delegate.CreateDelegate`?

I'm looking for a theoretical answer about the difference between the two approaches so I won't go into implementation details, but here is the jist of the implementation:

- For delegates: [Making Reflection Fly and Exploring Delegates](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/), by Jon Skeet
- For lambda expressions: using `Expression.Call`, `Expression.Parameter`, `Expression.Lambda` and `Expression.Compile`

Comment: To the person who voted to close; care to comment?

Comment: I don't understand why LambdaExpression delegate should be faster. Yes it generates msil, but Delegate.CreateDelegate creates delegate for already existing method, with already generated msil, so what's the difference?

Comment: That is precisely my question. Is there a difference, at the IL level, between calling a delegate created via `Delegate.CreateDelegate` and calling a delegate created via `LambdaExpression.Compile`? (even if this difference is small).

Comment: Well one is delegate (reference to function) and another is delegate. There is no difference between them. All the difference is in the functions those delegates point to.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between Delegate.CreateDelegate and LambdaExpression.Compile, Indeed the second do something more and can be more efficient in specific condition.

When you call Delegate.CreateDelegate manually you can call it with some overload with target value but in some case like static method, you don't have a target value.

In background when you don't have a target value, delegate is created with a generated method to pop useless value in stack before jump in real method. You can observe it with watcher : delegate have InPtr & InPtrAux

When IntPtrAux is assigned to a valid pointer, that means InPtr is called before to pop handle and jump to IntPtrAux. That's why a delegate to a delegate made for an instance method (handle is "this") is more efficient compared to the same for a static method.

In lambda expression compile to generated a delegate, Target is always used (for closure) and avoid the call/jump through IntPtrAux and is often efficient.